# Getting around the cmd character limitation

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, characters

I have a script that generates emails for me.

```
[18:35:50]Creating resolution ticket..
Enter ticket number: 
Enter users full name: 
Enter summary of issue: 
Enter what will happen or what you did: Hello ma'am, it has come to my attention that according to <agency> regulation and policy, if I where to get this escalated, they WILL NOT edit the registry. For some reason <agency> only allows a certain size, and I can not change that. My best advice to you, is
[18:37:27]Copied to clipboard press CNTRL-V to paste
```

As you can see, the command line character restriction cuts out before the I can finish generating the email. My question is, is there a way I can edit cmd, or a way I can work around this limitation?

Comment: Increase the size of the command window and its buffer size, or write your own command application, that allows for return characters

Comment: seems like it would be a better idea to output the text to a file, and copy it into the clipboard from there, rather than copying from the window.

Comment: Please include the script in your question. Otherwise we cannot answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't see how the script would be relevant to this issue..? It has to do with the command prompt having a character limit per command, not the script itself

Comment: @13aal Yes it is relevant. "On computers running Microsoft Windows XP or later, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 8191 characters". You are clearly managing much less than that. We need to figure out why. [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473)

Comment: @DavidPostill I can't post the entire script due to security of my agency, but I can probably post the main file that calls the modules and templates and such, I'll be posting it later, it's written in Ruby.

Comment: @13aal Yuck. I don't speak ruby :/

Comment: @DavidPostill Rubys what I learned with, so it's my baby. Lol, I also have a version written in Perl, Python, and C#. They aren't anywhere near done though.

Comment: @13aal If your scripts are written in Ruby, Perl, ... then your question is probably better suited to [so].

Comment: is your script using `<return>` for submission at the `Enter what will happen or what you did:` line?

Comment: Here's a link to the SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661155/getting-around-the-cmd-character-limit that shows most of the script

Comment: @hkdtam it uses ruby `gets` from a format module

Comment: you may try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236629/what-other-languages-have-features-and-or-libraries-similar-to-perls-format/236654#236654) for more fine-grained control to your text output